# std::cout giving inconsistent output with cv::Mat()

Tags: c++, opencv

I have read ground truth poses from some file into `std::vector<cv::Mat> gt_poses`. I was trying to output the values of the elements in `gt_poses[0]`.

`cv::Mat c_ = gt_poses[0];`

I am getting different outputs in the following two cases -

`std::cout << c_ << std::endl;  //correct output`

[0.9999889135360718, -0.002128534950315952, -0.004205819219350815, 0.003267206018790603;
0.002141749951988459, 0.9999927878379822, 0.003139850916340947, -0.0883823037147522;
0.004199104849249125, -0.003148823045194149, 0.9999861717224121, 4.566315174102783]

`for(int a = 0; a < gt_poses_[0].rows; a++) for(int b =0 ; b < gt_poses_[0].cols; b++) std::cout << gt_poses[0].at<float>(a, b) << " ";  //wrong output`

-2.000000 1.874997 -0.000000 -0.880613 2.000000 0.881036 -36893488147419103232.000000 1.874998 -0.000000 0.942186 -0.000000 -0.913262

What am I missing?

Comment: There isn't enough here to fully diagnose your problem.  However, one thing I would check is that there is actually an element in gt_poses.  You might be accessing an empty element, invoking undefined behavior

Comment: `std::cout << c_ << std::endl;` gives the right output. So, `gt_poses_[0]` is definitely not empty.

Comment: what happens if you use `gt_poses[0].at<float>(b, a)` ?

Comment: Are you sure float is the right type? Can you try double? Can you print mat.type() and mat.channels()?

Comment: @Micka Thanks! Using `gt_poses[0].at<double>(a,b)` did solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Micka in the comments, using `std::cout << gt_poses[0].at<double>(a,b) << std::end` solved the issue.